# Joomla 3.6 component and php code

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, url-routing, worldpay

I'm hoping someone can help me with this as I've burnt away many hours trying to find a solution?

I'm working on a Joomla 3.6.5 website using a component called OS Services Booking by OS SOLUTION.

I have the component configured as I would like and working (to a point) on a test server whilst I attempt to configure with WorldPay as the Payment Gateway for bookings.

The problem I am experiencing is that once a payment has been processed through WorldPay the "shopper response" (or redirect) only appears to be working so far until it experiences a 303 error and hangs.

I believe the reason for this 303 error is due to how the response from WorldPay is handled once it reaches the OS Services Booking component.

The shopper response url that is provided by the component and you put in your WorldPay configuration is - 
http://YOURDOMAINN/index.php?option=com_osservicesbooking&task=defaul_paymentconfirm&payment_method=os_worldpay

From what I understand this is the URL that WorldPay passes the results of the transaction back to. The data sent back from WorldPay reaches OS Services booking and as a result the component updates its database to log the transaction / book out the timeslot and send notification emails.

The last part of the process is for the component to redirect you to a page on your website informing the customer that the transaction has failed / succeeded.

To do this the component passes variables to create the url (this all appears to happen in the file... components > com_osservicesbooking > helpers > payment > omnipay.php starting around line 135)

```
protected function setPaymentSuccessUrl($id, $data = array())

    {

        $Itemid = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get->getInt('Itemid',0);

$this->paymentSuccessUrl = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_osservicesbooking&task=defaul_paymentconfirm&Itemid=' . $Itemid, false, false);

    }
```

I've traced the url (using wheregoes.com) and the way that the component handles this function appears to be via a 303 Redirect.

WorldPay doesn't appear to like this 303 Redirect and everything then stops and the customer is left hanging on WorldPays webpage (i believe they are called resultsY.html or resultsC.html rather than being redirected back to your website!

After researching and speaking with it seems that WorldPay might pass this Url redirect if the route taken uses a Meta Refresh rather than the 303 redirect.

With that in mind I am hopeful that if the code can be edited to perform a Meta Refresh then everything might work?

Something like (my PHP skills are none existent)

```
protected function setPaymentSuccessUrl($id, $data = array())

    {

        $Itemid = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get->getInt('Itemid',0);

echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL="'; 

        $this->paymentSuccessUrl = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_osservicesbooking&task=defaul_paymentconfirm&Itemid=' . $Itemid, false, false);

echo '">';      

    }
```

(But that doesn't work!)

If ANYONE can help it would be very much appreciated